# Were magnetic monopoles created before, during or after inflation?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

In the case that magnetic monopoles exist, when were they created? I thought that all particles were created after inflation, but I've read some comments recently that hint at a pre-inflationary creation of magnetic monopoles.

Answer (score 1):

Before. The point is that there were too many predicted, and no concept of inflation yet. [Here](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Watson/Watson4_4.html) is a reference that doesn't just gloss over it.

[Here](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Lqg5AAAAIAAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA171&dq=monopole+production+phase+transition+timeline&ots=GHAvSVSR7v&sig=W8zpH5rIZUxC_dGIpc8sz4u5Ja4#v=onepage&q&f=false) is the original paper by Guth, and [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119342/why-didnt-electroweak-symmetry-breaking-happen-earlier-than-it-did) has a nice drawing of the same timeline shown on that page. (Original [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/unify.html))

You ought to try that physics.SE thread and continue there for more details.